# How to optimize this simple but slow query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have a traveler table with around 200,000 records containing the user number (pk), country, and time of departure (datetime). My goal is to calculate the number of travelers that departed within one hour of each traveler's departure time for the same country.

So my input look like

```
| Travel_no | Date_time              | Country|
|-----------+------------------------|--------|
|         1 |         20160401150200 |      1 |
|         2 |         20160401160000 |      2 |
|         3 |         20160401010501 |      3 |
|         4 |         20160401090700 |      2 |
|         5 |         20160401155800 |      1 |
```

and my goal is to get

```
| Travel_no | Date_time              | Country| country_within_hr_cnt|
|-----------+------------------------|--------|----------------------|
|         1 |         20160401150200 |      1 |                    2 |
|         2 |         20160401160000 |      2 |                    1 |
|         3 |         20160401010501 |      3 |                    1 |
|         4 |         20160401090700 |      2 |                    1 |
|         5 |         20160401155800 |      1 |                    2 |
```

Right now I am using this query and its taking forever to run it ...

```sql
Select 
Travel_no
,Date_time
,Country
,(Select Count(Travel_no) from #temp1 b
  where 
  CAST(b.Date_time AS BIGINT) >= CAST(a.Date_time AS BIGINT) - 10000 
  and CAST(b.Date_time AS BIGINT) <= CAST(a.Date_time AS BIGINT) + 10000 
  and a.Country = b.Country
  ) 'country_within_hr_cnt'
FROM #temp1 a
GROUP BY 
Travel_no , Date_time, Country
```

Do you guys know if there is a way to make this run faster? Would an index on Date_time work well?

Comment: The casts hurt because they prevent use of any indexing on Date_time column.

Comment: The thing is the column Date_time is pulled from another table too and its currently stored as varchar. If I created another table to just do the cast and use that table for the above query would it work faster ?

Comment: b-tree index is a good choice for range scans on date field

Comment: Think of it this way: for each row in the grouped result of `a`, it has to scan the entire `b` table, because to evaluate the conditions, it must compute the cast. It will be fast when you arrange it so `b` is indexed on the column you're accessing in your condition, and your condition references the `b` column unadorned - i.e. the column values just as they're stored in `b`.

Comment: `Group by` has little sense in here. You calculate count in a subquery. All about `cast` hold.

Comment: @hatchet Thanks! What used  to run longer than 5 hours is now done in a 5 minutes ! Do you want to post the code below so I can park it as correct? 

@AlexB Can you elaborate a little bit on that ? It would produce an error without `Group by`

Comment: AlexB must be me ;). What kind of error it may produce? You have all columns from a single table plus a calculated column which always produces single result.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Sorry I didn't pay attention, I thought it is just a short form. You are right, originally I did `HAVING ABS(b.Date_time  - a.Date_time) < 10000 ` and it messed up the result without a `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it this way: for each row in the grouped result of a, it has to scan the entire b table, because to evaluate the conditions, it must compute the cast. It will be fast when you arrange it so b is indexed on the column you're accessing in your condition, and your condition references the b column unadorned - i.e. the column values just as they're stored in b.
You want your query to look like this:

```
Select 
Travel_no
,Date_time
,Country
,(Select Count(Travel_no) from #temp1 b
  where 
  b.Date_time >= a.Date_time - 10000 
  and b.Date_time <= a.Date_time + 10000 
  and a.Country = b.Country
  ) 'country_within_hr_cnt'
FROM #temp1 a
GROUP BY 
Travel_no , Date_time, Country
```

but even this might work

```
Select 
Travel_no
,Date_time
,Country
,(Select Count(Travel_no) from #temp1 b
  where 
  b.Date_time >= CAST(varchar(20),CAST(a.Date_time AS BIGINT) - 10000)
  and b.Date_time <= CAST(varchar(20),CAST(a.Date_time AS BIGINT) + 10000) 
  and a.Country = b.Country
  ) 'country_within_hr_cnt'
FROM #temp1 a
GROUP BY 
Travel_no , Date_time, Country
```

This assumes you've indexed b on Country and Date_time.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to cooment on two aspects here:

### Avoid Correlated Subqueries in SELECT:

Try to avoid correlated subqueries in SELECT statements at all costs.
The reason for this is that logically SQL server will have to run your sub-query for every row returned by outer SELECT statement, so if your outer SELECT returns 1000 rows your sub-query logically will be executed 1000 times. In practise SQL Server would ususally be able to optimise it, and move your sub-query from SELECT to the FROM clause, but if that does not happen you get slow performance.

### Functions in table joins:

As previous posters in comments have said, avoid using functions when joining tables, as this causes SQL Server to not use indexes, if any defined, on columns inside functions.

I would re-write your query as follows:

```
Select Travel_no, Date_time, Country, CAST( Date_time AS BIGINT ) AS ConvertedDateTime
INTO #TEMP2
from #temp1
-- Place WHERE conditions here that restrict result set


SELECT Travel_no, Date_time, Country, country_within_hr_cnt
FROM #TEMP2 AS tbl
    INNER JOIN
            ( SELECT a.Travel_no, COUNT( b.Travel_no ) AS country_within_hr_cnt
            FROM #TEMP2 AS a
                INNER JOIN #TEMP2 AS b
                    ON b.ConvertedDateTime >= a.ConvertedDateTime - 10000 AND b.ConvertedDateTime <= a.ConvertedDateTime + 10000
                        AND a.Country = b.Country
            GROUP BY Travel_no ) AS Summary
        ON tbl.Travel_no = Summary.Travel_no
-- Unless your Travel_no column contains duplicates you dnt' need group by
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Thanks! I would add index on `TEMP2` as well.

Comment: Add index on following columns Country, ConvertedDateTime, Travel_no